How To: Falling circle objects in the viewport (video example)

Things I want to achieve:

the circles start outside the viewport (top side)
circles start falling in the bottom and collide with other circles.

This is my current code. I was able to achieve falling physics but the collision is quite hard to figure out. In the example video, there's also a slight bounce effect when the circle collided with other circle but that's optional. The falling effect + collision is what I needed.
// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs, sort_constructors_first
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
import 'package:flame/collisions.dart';
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:lumi/utils/print_debug.dart';

import 'budget_page.dart';

class FallingCircles extends FlameGame with HasCollisionDetection {
  final List<BudgetValue> values;
  final Color bgColor;

  @override
  Color backgroundColor() => bgColor;

  FallingCircles({
    required this.values,
    required this.bgColor,
  });

  @override
  void onLoad() {
    addAll([
      ScreenHitbox(),
      ...values.mapIndexed(
        (i, e) => Ball(e, i),
      )
    ]);
  }
}

class Ball extends CircleComponent with HasGameReference<FlameGame>, CollisionCallbacks {
  final BudgetValue budgetValue;
  final int index;
  late Vector2 velocity;

  Ball(
    this.budgetValue,
    this.index,
  ) {
    paint = Paint()..color = budgetValue.color;
    radius = budgetValue.highest ? 100 : 66;
  }

  static const double speed = 500;
  static const degree = math.pi / 180;
  final _gravity = 20;
  late var _velocityTmp = Vector2.zero();

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();
    final hitBox = CircleHitbox(
      radius: radius,
      isSolid: true,
      collisionType: CollisionType.active,
    );

    velocity = Vector2(
      0,
      speed,
    );

    addAll([
      hitBox,
    ]);
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    super.update(dt);
    velocity.y += _gravity * dt;

    _velocityTmp
      ..setFrom(velocity)
      ..scale(dt);

    position.add(_velocityTmp);
  }

  double get getSpawnAngle {
    final random = math.Random().nextDouble();
    final spawnAngle = lerpDouble(0, 360, random)!;

    return spawnAngle;
  }
}

